# SED: Insert a string with special character

Tags: linux, shell, file, sed, insert

I want to INSERT a string with "**'**" as special character in multiple files. All the files in which I want to insert have a line after which I want to perform my INSERT.

eg:

**File Before INSERT:**

...

FROM LOCAL :LOAD_FILE

REJECTED DATA :REJECT_PATH

...

**File After INSERT:**

...

FROM LOCAL :LOAD_FILE

**DELIMITER AS '|'**

REJECTED DATA :REJECT_PATH

...

I've tried writing down many SED commands but they are generating errors. One of them is:

sed 'LOAD_FILE/a/ DELIMITER AS \'\|\'/g' SOURCE > DESTINATION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using surrounding double quotes:

```
sed "/FROM LOCAL :LOAD_FILE/s//&\nDELIMITER AS '|'/" file
```

or single quotes (safer to avoid unwanted variable expansion):

```
sed '/FROM LOCAL :LOAD_FILE/s//&\nDELIMITER AS '"'|'"'/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk  -v line='DELIMITER AS '"'|'"'' '1; /LOAD_FILE/{print line }' input
FROM LOCAL :LOAD_FILE
DELIMITER AS '|'
REJECTED DATA :REJECT_PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/LOAD_FILE/aDELIMITER AS '\'\|\' file
```

This appends the line `DELIMITER AS \'\|\'` following the match on `LOAD_FILE`

N.B. The sed command is in two parts, the `/LOAD_FILE/aDELIMITER AS` is concatenated with  `\'\|\'`

If you prefer:

```
sed 's/LOAD_FILE/&\nDELIMITER AS '\'\|\''/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of putting it :

`sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/LOAD_FILE\n/LOAD_FILE\nDELIMITER AS \x27|\x27\n/g'`

about syntax I used :

[How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

Answer (score 0):

Use the command below to add any charecters in mid of words.

```
sed 's/^../&\./' filename
```

Use with `-i` to update the file

```
sed -i 's/^../&\./' filename
```